# Getting the next Value in a ArrayList(Not working)

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm trying to get the next value in a specific arraylist every time a user presses a button (using Swing).

This is my attempt at it:

```
private void BNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int i = 0;
        Parse p = new Parse();
        temp = p.getTemp();
        temp2 = p.getTemp2();
        temp3 = p.getTemp3();

        if (CBUniversities.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
            LNumStudents.setText("Number of students:  " + temp);
            Student s = p.getMacList().get(i+1);
            jTextField2.setText(s.getFirstName());
            TLastName.setText(s.getSurName());
            jTextArea1.setText(s.getAddress());
            i++;
        }
}
```

Where Parse is a class, containing getter methods for 3 integers`temp,temp2,temp3, and a getter for an ArrayList.`
`Student s` is an object of the Student class, where every student has a firstname, surname and address (initialized in a constructor).

When this if statement is executed it displays a students info in the specified fields, however, this only works for the first two students. After that, the `i` value never seems to increase?

I tried to place a `println` check to see it's value during the if statement, but it only changes once, oddly enough.

I also tried to make this into a for loop, yet the value again only seems to change once (of i).

Parse has this getter method I'm using

```
public ArrayList<Student> getMacList() {
        return mac;
}
```

Also CBUniversities is a variable as such:

```
private javax.swing.JComboBox CBUniversities;
```

I'm not sure what's gone wrong here, any ideas?

Comment: `int i` seems to be in wrong scope. Try moving it to the class level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared `i` within the scope of a method, so every time your method executes it reinitializes `i`.

Instead, declare an instance variable by putting `private int i = 0;` outside of your method, but still within the class scope.

Comment: It should be called something other than `i` if its not being used in loops, etc.

Comment: Wow, I feel bad for not realizing this sooner, thanks!

Comment: @TTEd Don't feel bad!  You'll have this experience 99% of the time you fix a bug.  It's always something obvious.